# static foo = "bar" vs. MyClass.foo = "bar"

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, static-members

In ECMAScript 6, what is the difference between the following syntaxes:

```
class MyClass {
  static foo = "bar"
}
```

```
class MyClass {}

MyClass.foo = "bar"
```

Comment: The first systax is invalid

Comment: The first one is not ES6. It is a [Stage 1 Proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) (also you have an invalid `=` in the first too). But in that proposal, there is no differences between those two code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is not part of ES6, it's [currently only a proposal](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties) so may exist in future versions of Javascript.

However, it's functionally identical to the second example - you could try it in the [Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/) to see what they get compiled down to. You can use the first syntax if you're transpiling your code, but you'll need to include the appropriate flags (for Babel, this code require the 'stage-1' flag to compile).

Answer (score -1):

Syntax is wrong, but in first example foo cannot be modifed, in second can